# How can I find out if the gradle daemon is running?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-daemon

I am developing Android applications with Android Studio 2.0. I read in a lot of blogposts that enabling the gradle daemon should increase the build performance drastically.

My problem is, that I do not know how to check if the daemon is running. I added the line

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

to the `gradle.properties` file but Android Studio shows me a `unused property` warning, so I am not sure if the daemon is actually running. How can I find out if the daemon is actually running?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265217/how-to-know-whether-you-are-running-inside-a-gradle-daemon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building and running app via Gradle and Android Studio is slower than via Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775197/building-and-running-app-via-gradle-and-android-studio-is-slower-than-via-eclips)

Answer (score 9):

Long time passed since the question is asked, but I see no exact answer to the question:

> How can I find out if the gradle daemon is running?

Running in terminal `gradle --status` will give the status of the gradle. You'll see "No Gradle daemons are running" message if there's no gradle daemon running.

[image: No daemon]

Otherwise, you'll see status of the daemon.

[image: Daemon running]

Comment: Isn't this working only for standalone Gradle? Or am i missing something?  
AFAIK Android studio runs Gradle Daemon internally. So this solution will return following error `gradle: The term 'gradle' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program....`  unless user had set up gradle outside of Android Studio beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio (based on IntelliJ) *always* uses the Gradle Daemon internally. See about

- [IntelliJ/Gradle integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html)

You only need to enable the Daemon for builds you invoke on the command-line and here's how to do that:

```
echo "org.gradle.daemon=true" >> $PROJECT_DIR/gradle.properties
```